# Replacing windows shell for everybody but the system administrator

Tags: windows, hardening

[cross posted from [superuser](https://superuser.com/q/253688/68818) - I believe the question is also relevant here]

I'm trying to harden a windows 7 machine, including replacing the default login shell from explorer.exe to a custom application.
This part works well.

However, I also want that the administrator will still be able to manage the machine, so I modified the user specific key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\shell
```

back to `explorer.exe` - but when I log on I get a single windows file explorer window, and not the full desktop.

does any one know how to configure the normal desktop shell only to a specific user?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think the shell needs to be set to `explorer` without the `.exe` to work.  (It's been awhile since I've messed with alternate shells.)  On my Windows 7 machine, which hasn't had the shell changed, there is no `shell` value at all.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you're going about this the wrong way round, instead of mucking around with vaguely documented registry keys, I think you'd be better off just defining a proper GPO (group policy object).
I dont have an environment handy to verify this, but I assume its possible to define a custom shell according to the user's group...

Comment: In non enterprise versions of windows 7, there is no (easy) way to setup different configurations for different users.

Comment: Ah, if its non-enterprise then you're probably not domain-joined, and hence no GPO....

Answer (score 0):

See the MSDN article on [different shells for different users](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms838576%28v=winembedded.5%29.aspx).

Comment: an answer which just consists of a link will get downvoted/deleted. We generally expect local content that can stand alone if the external link rots. Of course, having the link as an extra is good too.